# React Event Handler Button Click Not Working on First Click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, events, event-handling

I am making the Recipe Box project from Free Code Camp. I have an event handler that is supposed to send an object that contains an array property made up of ingredients up to a parent component which will display the items in the array. The problem is, when I first click the button that fires the handler, it sends an empty array even though there are ingredients entered by the user, and the second time I click it, it sends the ingredients from the previous button click, and it goes on like this every time the button is clicked. How can I fix this?

Method in question:

```
  handleSubmit() {
    let ingredientsArrayUpdater = (ingredient) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ingredientsArr: [
          ...prevState.ingredientsArr,
          ingredient
        ]
      }))
    }

    let splitUserInput = this.state.ingredients.split(',');

    splitUserInput.map(ingredient => {
      return(
      ingredientsArrayUpdater(ingredient.trim())
    )
    });

    let recipeObject = {
      recipeName: this.state.recipe,
      ingredientList: this.state.ingredientsArr,
      idNumber: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000) + 1)
    }
    this.props.addRecipe(recipeObject);
  }
```

Code for button that triggers event handler:

```
 <button onClick={e => {this.handleSubmit()}}
               className="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">
               Add Recipe
              <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
 </button>
```

Here is the github repository to see all the components. Index.js is the parent component.

https://github.com/EsTrevino/recipe-box-project/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you aren't updating the state when you think you are. You also aren't waiting for the updated state, after you call `setState`. I'm not sure about all that you're trying to achieve in this method, but a start is:

```
handleSubmit() {
  let splitUserInput = this.state.ingredients.split(',');
  let newArray = this.state.ingredientsArr.concat(splitUserInput.map(a => a.trim()));

  this.setState({ingredientsArr: newArray});

  let recipeObject = {
    recipeName: this.state.recipe,
    ingredientList: newArray,
    idNumber: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000) + 1)
  }
  this.props.addRecipe(recipeObject);
}
```

That's "cheating" using what we know the state will be updated to. You can also use a callback for `setState` to be more unidirectional.

```
handleSubmit() {
  let splitUserInput = this.state.ingredients.split(',');
  let newArray = this.state.ingredientsArr.concat(splitUserInput.map(a => a.trim()));

  this.setState({ingredientsArr: newArray}, () => {
    let recipeObject = {
      recipeName: this.state.recipe,
      ingredientList: newArray,
      idNumber: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000) + 1)
    }
    this.props.addRecipe(recipeObject);
  });
}
```

Same difference, IMO.